# Restore original file which was deleted during patch creation

Tags: git

I have just started using git. For some reason I have to create a patch of my changes which inclueds (file modification + 4 new files creation). I am successfully able to cretae a patch. But during this process some how those files which I have created got deleted. I want those files again. How can I get that.

Comment: That sounds as if you manually created the patches. Use `git format-patch` to generate patch files for your (committed) changes.

Answer (score 0):

If those files were committed, a simple

```
git checkout -
# or
git checkout -f HEAD
```

should be enough to checkout again the content of the working directory (but it can override any current - not-yet-committed - work), so be careful (a `git stash` could be useful first).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use patches? Assuming where you are sending them, they are using git as well, you can just send them a git bundle. Take a look at the `git bundle` command here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html

If you generated the patches for the new files by taking the output of `git diff`, you won't be able to issue any git commands to get them back as they were never part of anything that git tracked. Simply recreate the files by cutting out the contents of the patches you made.

If you generated the patches for the new files after having committed them to history you can get back to the original state of that latest commit by any one of these methods:

```
git stash 
git checkout -- .
git reset --hard
```

**be careful that you don't have existing work when doing this**. Stash is the safest one of all those commands as it stores the state of your modifications in a reference in history. In case you zapped something, you can get it back with `stash pop`